# Error al enviar correo por medio de API

Tags: angular, typescript

tegno uana funcion la cual envia correo dependiendo los correos seleccionados, el detalle es que me da error, si le asigno un correo fijo si me lo envia pero me marca error. no se por que no me reconoce de que se envia me salte el mensaje de que si se envio.

```
sendCorreo(){
this.submitted = true;

//create json de envio de correo
let jsonSendmail = {   
  destinatario: 'pedro.gutierrez@samm.com', 
  con_copia: this.correo_copia, 
  asunto: this.asunto, 
  cuerpo_mensaje: this.mensaje,
};
console.log(jsonSendCorreo);
for (let correo of this.correos_seleccionados) {
  this.apiprovedors.postenvicorreo(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonSendmail))).subscribe({
    next: (v) =>{
      if(v != null ){
        this.limpiacampos();
        this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Completado', detail: 'Se ha enviado el correo correctamente.', life: 3000});
      }else{
        this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'No se puedo enviar el correo.', life: 3000});
      }
    },
    error: (e) =>{
      this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Hubo un problema en el envio de correo.', life: 3000});
      console.error(e);
    }, 
    complete: () => console.info('complete') 
  });
}
```

}

formulario:

```
<div>
                    <label class="font-bold">Correos</label>
                    <p-chips placeholder="Correos" separator="," [(ngModel)]="correos" placeholder=""></p-chips>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Correo copia</label>
                    <input pInputText type="email" placeholder="Ingresa correo" [(ngModel)]="correo_copia"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Asunto</label>
                    <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="asunto"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="font-bold">Mensaje</label>
                    <textarea pInputTextarea rows="3" cols="30" [(ngModel)]="mensaje"></textarea>
                </div>
```

Igual aplico un let para que que recorre mi array de correo[] y vaya enviado uno por uno pero tampoco me funciona.

Error:
HttpErrorResponse
error:
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'C', "Correo env"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (…, text: 'Correo enviado correctamente'}
headers:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message:
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8081/api/servicio/proveedor/envio-mail/mail"
name:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok:
false
status:
200
statusText:
"OK"
url:
"http://localhost:8081/api/servicio/proveedor/enviar-mail/mail"

Comment: Sin saber qué hacen los métodos de los servicios que llamas ni qué devuelven, ni siquiera qué te imprime en consola ese `console.error(e);` va a ser realmente complicado *adivinar* qué está pasando. Por favor añade los mensajes de error que obtienes, así como las respuestas obtenidas del servicio.

Comment: Listo amigo @Benito-B

Comment: Probaste el código sin el `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...`? Supongo que tu servicio espera un objeto, no veo la necesidad de usar stringify y luego parsear el objeto que literalmente acabas de crear... El error te lo da al parsear la respuesta de tu servicio?? Podrías mostrar el código del servicio postenvicorreo??

Comment: ya amigo, sin eso me marca error asi que tengo que poner algo, lo deje en JSON y me da esto @Benito-B: Array(2)
0
: 
"peter@hotmail.com"
1: 
"peter89@gmail.com"
length: 
2
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
proveedor.component.ts:987 
Object
asunto: 
"test"
con_copia: 
"peter89@gmail.com"
cuerpo_mensaje: 
"test"
destinatario
: 
"peter@hotmail"
[[Prototype]]: 
Object
apis-proveedor.service.ts:122 
JSON
parse: 
ƒ parse()
stringify
: 
ƒ stringify()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
: 
"JSON"
[[Prototype]]: 
Object